# Server is sending back text/html instead of javascript files

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-6, iis-8

I have done a rewrite on the server using these conditions:
  AngularWildCard: (.*) - rewrite to appjs/views/
  AngularCondtions: 
(appjs/modules/.*|appjs/agent/*|appjs/user/.*|content/.*|scripts/.*) - none

When I load the page the server is sending back the index page for every java-script request. I can't figure out why when the AngularConditions should not rewrite those request.

Note: I wrote this in IIS Manager